# Notepad++: How to set different color for odd and even lines?

Tags: notepad++

is possible to set different color for odd and even lines? And how?

Like in this image:
[image]

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: No it is it not possible.

Comment: You *might* be able to cobble together code to do so using LuaScript: see https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/11913/syntax-highlight-entire-line-or-to-end-of-line/6

Comment: I'm trying to implement the luascript and not succeeding.